# average a 3D array to get lower resolution

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array of shape (100,100,100). I would like to reduce the resolution to (50,50,50). What is the fastest way to do this?

So in 1D I would like to turn

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

into

```
[1.5, 3.5, 5.5]
```

A 2D example would be

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

into

```
[[2, 4], 
 [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution...

```
def change_resolution(x, dimx, dimy, dimz, N):
    x = x.reshape(dimx*N, dimy*N, dimz, N)
    x = x.sum(axis=3)/N
    x = x.reshape(dimx*N, dimy, N, dimz)
    x = x.sum(axis=2)/N
    x = x.reshape(dimx, N, dimy, dimz)
    x = x.sum(axis=1)/N
    return x
```

with dimx etc being the new resolution and dimx*N being the resolution if the 3D input array x.